# Python (py.exe) closes when 'flag' becomes False

Tags: python

When responding with 'Y' to the repeat input, the code requests another name and another mountain, as expected. If responding with 'N' to the 'repeat' input, Python closes, instead of printing what's next. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

```
responses = {}

polling_active = True

while polling_active:

    name = input('\nPlease state your name: ')
    mount = input('What mountain would you like to climb? ')
    responses[name] = mount

    repeat = input('Would anyone else like to attend? (Y/N) ')
    if repeat == 'n':
        polling_active = False

print('\nPoll is now closed. Results are:')
for name, mount in responses.items():
    print(f"{name.title()} would like to climb {mount.title()}!")
```

Comment: It's working for me

Comment: Change to `print(f"{name} would like to climb {mount}!")`

Comment: To clarify what means by closes; does the interpreter just exit with no error? Or are you receiving some form of error? As others have mentioned, the code works for me also. Is there more code that you've not shared?

Comment: At least it works for someone. I did your change @stovfl. No luck. I'm using Python 3.8 and Sublime Text, if that makes any difference. I have this same problem with other, similar code.

Comment: @amitchone The interpreter closes. I edit the code in Sublime, save it, then open the file in the interpreter. I put in a name, a mountain, and then when I type N and press 'ENTER', the interpreter closes.

Comment: Just tried it in Command Prompt. Works perfectly. Any guess as to why Python closes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working well - at least for me.

One thing - you ask for input in Capital 'Y/N', and your question also mentioned using 'N' - while the code checks for small letters ('n').

You may want to do:

```
if repeat.lower() == 'n':
```

But I'm really not sure that's the issue for you.

Comment: I've tried both ways. I'm really confused, as it seems to be working for everyone except me. I have no idea why the interpreter just closes. At least my code works, I suppose.

Comment: Just tried it in Command Prompt. Works perfectly. Any guess as to why Python closes?

Comment: what do you mean by command prompt vs. python? How do you execute your program?

Comment: I double-click the .py file, which opens it in 'py.exe'. Is that not the interpreter? I'm new to all this. When I type 'N' in 'py.exe' it closes instead of printing the last few lines.

Comment: If the command prompt works well, your program is fine. I'm not familiar with py.exe as a Windows application. My guess is that the program completes successfully and exits, and that happens too fast for you to read the output.

Comment: That might be it. Thanks for the help.